# What is the regex syntax for multiline (filebeat)?

Tags: regex, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I need the regex syntax for multiline.pattern for my filebeat.yml. Please find the attached logs line for which I need the regex syntax.
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBvtS.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance this one will be enough:

```yaml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  # https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html
  multiline.pattern: '^.{3} \d{2}, \d{4}'
  multiline.negate: true
  multiline.match: after
```

Log example:

```
Jul 03, 2019 12:14:05 PM com.splunk
```

Comment: I glad to help you ;)